# Adding async features to ServiceStack OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am considering creating an async fork of ServiceStack.OrmLite. I can see that `System.Data` is referenced in version 2.0.0. I need to add a reference to the 4.0.0 version to get access to the async methods on `DbCommand`. My strategy would be to go through the code and add async versions of methods by using `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, `ExecuteReaderAsync` and `ExecuteScalarAsync` instead of their sync counterparts. Because the async methods are defined on `DbCommand` instead of `IDbCommand` I would need to cast the `IDbCommand` to `DbCommand`.

Are anybody aware of any issues with this approach - is it ok to update reference to 4.0.0 version, any problmes with async in the native drivers for MySql, pgsql, firebird, ormlite?

If not then I will start the work and see how it turs out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mythz (http://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz) wants to keep it at 3.5. You might want to ask if he wants to branch that.

Comment: I have successfully used DbCommand async methods with Dapper. Easy to alter even for .net 4 (just TPL, no async/await). I recommend.